# How to use Keychain for saving password like GenericKeychain sample code

Tags: ios, encryption, passwords, keychain

I want to save user's id and password in App.

What is recommendable encryption way when I save id and password.

I'm finding more safe way from Jailbreak or Hacker.

How about GenericKeychain sample code ?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797

I can't have confidence about safe how to use Keychain like GenericKeychain sample code.

Please tell me some advices. Thank you ^^*

Answer (score 24):

You can use the Security framework

`#import <Security/Security.h>`

**To save a username and password for a server:**

```
-(void) saveUsername:(NSString*)user withPassword:(NSString*)pass forServer:(NSString*)server {

    // Create dictionary of search parameters
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)(kSecClassInternetPassword),  kSecClass, server, kSecAttrServer, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes, nil];

    // Remove any old values from the keychain
    OSStatus err = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict);

    // Create dictionary of parameters to add
    NSData* passwordData = [pass dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)(kSecClassInternetPassword), kSecClass, server, kSecAttrServer, passwordData, kSecValueData, user, kSecAttrAccount, nil];

    // Try to save to keychain
    err = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict, NULL);

}
```

**To remove:**

```
-(void) removeAllCredentialsForServer:(NSString*)server {

    // Create dictionary of search parameters
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)(kSecClassInternetPassword),  kSecClass, server, kSecAttrServer, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnData, nil];

    // Remove any old values from the keychain
    OSStatus err = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict);

}
```

**To read:**

```
-(void) getCredentialsForServer:(NSString*)server {

    // Create dictionary of search parameters
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)(kSecClassInternetPassword),  kSecClass, server, kSecAttrServer, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnData, nil];

    // Look up server in the keychain
    NSDictionary* found = nil;
    CFDictionaryRef foundCF;
    OSStatus err = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict, (CFTypeRef*)&foundCF);

    // Check if found
    found = (__bridge NSDictionary*)(foundCF);
    if (!found) 
        return;

    // Found
    NSString* user = (NSString*) [found objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
    NSString* pass = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[found objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

Comment: You now need to use __bridge (let automatic fixups do it for you) to cast between the ObjC and C code in the above.

Comment: You need to check for err == errSecItemNotFound after SecItemCopyMatching