# How can all of my ViewControllers for iOS have user login information available to them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I'm not sure what the correct pattern for this situation is, so I'm not really sure what to search for here...

Basically, I want to have my iOS (iPhone) application start with a login page always. From there, I need the rest of the application's ViewControllers to be able to access the login information, and I'm not sure what the best way to do this is...

- Do I create some form of global variable somehow?
- Do I pass in an instance of the class to each ViewController and have a property for each ViewController to hold this login information?
- Do I store some token in the cache/temp/appfolder somehow that each one can read from to get login information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could go with a shared instance of an object that holds the users credentials. You could also put it in a property or object in your app delegate or you could write it to disk (either NSUserDefaults or a special file).

For sensitive login credentials however, the recommended thing would be to use the keychain for persistence.

I think I would go with a combination of keychain for persisting the data and a shared instance or class method  to retrieve it throughout the app.

Comment: +1 for mentioning alternatives to NSUserDefaults for sensitive data concerns.

Comment: It's better to create this shared instance as singletone. using appdelegate for this could cause problems with reading/debugging code. and you can accidentally create two of this instances. also this leads to importing appdelegate in every class

Comment: @Roma I don't agree. We don't know enough about any other requirements for the app. But to just say a singleton would be better or access through appDelegate would be causing problems is wrong in my opinion. It might be - but it is not generally true.

Comment: I agree with Mario. Keychain is probably the best bet if you are 'concerned' about security. There is an in-depth tutorial on the Ray Wenderlich website on how to use the keychain. http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 2):

There is concept called `NSUserDefaults` in iOS to which is used to store light weight information in iPhone memory.

Look at this examples to learn storing and retrieving data in `NSUserDefaults` : [example1](http://codeexamples.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/nsuserdefaults-example/) and [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults).

**EDIT :**

As you want to store login and password, use `keychain`. Here is an [keychain example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535639/how-to-use-keychain-for-saving-password-like-generickeychain-sample-code).

Comment: Is this a safe area to store user information (username/hashed password)?

Comment: Please use the keychain, not `NSUserDefaults`, for storing passwords.

Comment: @michael I agree that keychain is better when you store sensitive data. I found a very simple example and I posted a link to it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults to store the username/password, but if you just need the login credentials or a token to make new service calls, and you usually send them on the headers of an HTTP request, I would just set them on the headers of your service classes, so you don't really need to store it anywhere.

If you want to store the info from a login response (like name, email, etc), I usually have a Constant class in my projects to keep global references and other constants (I don't like to keep stuff in the AppDelegate and have it included on every class), and I have a User class with all the user info. I keep a reference of that User object on the Constant class. It's simpler than having to pass it down to every ViewController in your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple, yet useful approach:

Use `NSUserDefaults` for storing a `BOOL` named `didAuthUser`

Whenever you want show a view controller that needs authentication check for `didAuthUser` (this is usually the root view controller) like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([prefs boolForKey:@"didAuthUser"]) {
    //Get stored credentials
}else{
    //Show login view controller
}
```

So, when a user starts using yout app, you'll be able to show a log in view controller. If the user has already logged in, you must check the stored credentials (use the keychain, **do not store sensitive information in NSUserDefaults**)

Using the keychain is not a very straightforward process, you may want to use something [like this](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain)

If you use `sskeychain`, a simple implementation would use the following methods:

`+ (BOOL)setPassword:(NSString *)password forService:(NSString *)serviceName account:(NSString *)account;`

`+ (NSString *)passwordForService:(NSString *)serviceName account:(NSString *)account;`

Note that the method for retrieving the password asks for an account, you may use `NSUserDefaults` for this. It's ok to store the account on `NSUserDefaults` as long as the password is secure on the keychain.

This way you can access the login data all across the app.

Happy coding!