# iOS7 app backward compatible with iOS5 regarding unique identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uniqueidentifier

My app is compatible with iOS5 and iOS6.
Until now I had no problem using:

```
NSString DeviceID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

Now with iOS7 and with uniqueIdentifier not working anymore I changed to:

```
NSString DeviceID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

The problem is, this would not work for iOS5.

How can I achieve backward compatibility with iOS5?

I tried this, with no luck:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 60000
    // iOS 6.0 or later
    NSString DeviceID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
#else
    // iOS 5.X or earlier
    NSString DeviceID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
#endif
```

Comment: might [openUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) be a suitable replacement for you?

Comment: openUDID is wrong answer. http://blog.appsfire.com/udid-is-dead-openudid-is-deprecated-long-live-advertisingidentifier/

Comment: You can't use compile time directives for this, you need a runtime check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best and recommend option by Apple is:

```
 NSString *adId = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
```

Use it for every device above 5.0.

For 5.0 you have to use uniqueIdentifier. The best to check if it's available is:

```
if (!NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager"))
```

Combining that will give you:

```
- (NSString *) advertisingIdentifier
{
    if (!NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")) {
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"uniqueIdentifier");
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            return [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:selector];
        }
        //or get macaddress here http://iosdevelopertips.com/device/determine-mac-address.html
    }
    return [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz Krukowski.
Still getting: "No visible @interface for 'UIDevice' declares the selector 'uniqueIdentifier'" error because Apple removed the uniqueIdentifier property from the UIDevice class.

Comment: Ok than modify that part: return [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]; for some other UID in that case :) either generate on your own or use UUID in that case or get MACAddress - updated my answer

Comment: Ok I found another safer way to use respondsToSelector and performSelector - that should not raise errors.

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz Krukowski!

Comment: Apple no longer allow the user of `ASIdentifierManager` without any advertisements in the app. You will be rejected if you use `ASIdentifierManager` without showing a banner.

Answer (score 1):

Why just not to use `CFUUIDRef` and be independent with iOS verion?

```
CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

self.uuidString = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL,uuidRef);

CFRelease(uuidRef);
```

And of course remember calculated `uuidString` in the Keychain(in case of application removal)?

[Here is written how to use keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535639/how-to-use-keychain-for-saving-password-like-generickeychain-sample-code)

Answer (score 0):

As hard replacement of static macro, you can try dynamic if statement to check it.

UIDevice has property named 'systemVersion' and you can check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/systemVersion).