# uniqueDeviceIdentifier in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I have an issue where I previously used the `uniqueDeviceIdentifier` to check if the customer had activated a subscription in an app. Now when customers have updated to iOS7 I can no longer check the `uniqueDeviceIdentifier` and the customers therefore no longer have a subscription. I will start using the `identifierForVendor` to start subscriptions from now but I don't know what to do with old users that has already installed iOS7. I'm willing to give away subscriptions to any user who already has started the app but I don't know how I could possible check if the app has ever been started before.

Is there anyway to get around this dilemma with any check for install date or similar? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you store the old identifier or any other account information (like a username)? You could that sort of thing to check.

Comment: Sadly nothing is stored in the app. Only the uniqueDeviceIdentifier on the backend

Comment: Check my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770100/ios7-app-backward-compatible-with-ios5-regarding-unique-identifier

Answer (score 1):

No there is not solution to problem unless you have another way to identify your users.
If it the subscription is bought via an IAP you can add a restore functionality to your app.

Also just to warn you, the `identifierForVendor` will be reset if the user removes all apps by the same vendor. In iOS7 there is noway to identify device any more, because you should have identified the user.

Answer (score 0):

use can use advertisingIdentifier of addsupport framework of ios

Comment: Note that this changes whenever you turn off ad tracking in the settings, or select the option (also in the settings) to generate the new one.