# How to get Device UDID in programmatically in iOS7?

Tags: iphone, udid

How to get device UDID in programatically in iOS7.`[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` I was used this code This is deprecated iOS7. how to get the device UDID. The UDID String changing when I delete the app and the reinstall means the UDID was getting different one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

Comment: give a reputation then only is useful to other is going more reputation

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's work 100% to all the version

other best option recommend by apple use [ASIdentifierManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html)

[ios7-app-backward-compatible-with-ios5-regarding-unique-identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770100/ios7-app-backward-compatible-with-ios5-regarding-unique-identifier)

this link tell you how to handle and use custom framework

[uidevice-uniqueidentifier-property-is-deprecated-what-now](http://iosapplove.com/archive/2013/01/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-property-is-deprecated-what-now/)

iOS 9

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"20B0DDE7-6087-4607-842A-E97C72E4D522"];
NSLog(@"%@",uuid);
NSLog(@"%@",[uuid UUIDString]);
```

or

it support only ios 6.0 and above

code to use `[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];`

```
NSUUID *deviceId;
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
deviceId = [NSUUID initWithUUIDString:@"UUID-STRING-VALUE"];
#else
deviceId = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor;
#endif
```

ios 5 to use like

```
 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)]) {
    // This is will run if it is iOS6
    return [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
} else {
   // This is will run before iOS6 and you can use openUDID or other 
   // method to generate an identifier
}
```

Comment: [NSUUID initWithUUIDString:@"UUID-STRING-VALUE"]; is missing alloc.

Comment: I'm testing on iOS 9 and getting 'No known class method for selector 'initWithUUIDString''. Why so?

Comment: Create an NSUUID from a string such as "E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F". Returns nil for invalid strings. @JayprakashDubey

Comment: you can use with alloc NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"20B0DDE7-6087-4607-842A-E97C72E4D522"]; @JayprakashDubey

Comment: for the ASIdentifierManager, will you get rejected from the AppStore if you do not serve ads?

Comment: @codercat - My comment was a question.  Are you saying it WILL get rejected if not serving ads?

Answer (score 20):

UDID is no longer available in iOS 6+ due to security / privacy reasons. Instead, use identifierForVendor or advertisingIdentifier.

Please go through [this](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/09/udid-apis-in-ios-6/) link.

```
   NSString* uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]; // IOS 6+
   NSLog(@"UDID:: %@", uniqueIdentifier);
```

> UPDATE for iOS 8+

```
+ (NSString *)deviceUUID
{
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]])
        return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];

    @autoreleasepool {

        CFUUIDRef uuidReference = CFUUIDCreate(nil);
        CFStringRef stringReference = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidReference);
        NSString *uuidString = (__bridge NSString *)(stringReference);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:uuidString forKey:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        CFRelease(uuidReference);
        CFRelease(stringReference);
        return uuidString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i was used above code. but when i delete and then reinstall my application generating different UDID. It will dynamically changing.

Comment: the above example is not giving right value as device UDID and also value is changing system by system

Comment: I believe that's Apple's intention. If the user has reason to delete the app, they should no longer be trackable.

Comment: Don't worry I also have solution for that. Use Keychain... :)

Answer (score 6):

In Swift you can get the device UUID like this

```
let uuid = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
println(uuid)
```

Comment: He was asking about the UDID, not the UUID.

Answer (score 2):

Use identifierForVendor or advertisingIdentifier.

**identifierForVendor:**

```
An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device to the app’s vendor. (read-only)

The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.
```

**advertisingIdentifier:**

```
An alphanumeric string unique to each device, used only for serving advertisements. (read-only)

Unlike the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice, the same value is returned to all vendors. This identifier may change—for example, if the user erases the device—so you should not cache it.
```

Also, see Apple's documentation for the identifierForVendor and advertisingIdentifier.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7, Apple now always returns a fixed value when querying the MAC to specifically thwart the *MAC as base for an ID* scheme. So you now really should use [-[UIDevice identifierForVendor]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) or create a per-install UUID.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6993325/1597744) SO Question.

Comment: i was used this code[UIDvice identifierForVendor] but when i run my application it return the ID,and then delete and agin run my application it will return the deferent  id. It will generate random id.

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 3.0:**

```
UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```

**old version**

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor
```

**you want a string:**

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
```

Answer (score 0):

Have 2 solutions:

- You can use identifierForVendor after that store them to keychain and use later. Because value of keychain will not changed when re-install app.
- You can try [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID)

Answer (score 0):

**For getting UDID:** (If you're using this Might be App store guys won't allow it --> As per my concern)

```
- (NSString *)udid
{
void *gestalt = dlopen("/usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY);
CFStringRef (*MGCopyAnswer)(CFStringRef) = (CFStringRef (*)(CFStringRef))(dlsym(gestalt, "MGCopyAnswer"));
return CFBridgingRelease(MGCopyAnswer(CFSTR("UniqueDeviceID")));
}

 **Entitlements:**
 <key>com.apple.private.MobileGestalt.AllowedProtectedKeys</key>
   <array>
<string>UniqueDeviceID</string>
</array>
```

**For Getting UUID**:

```
    self.uuidTxtFldRef.text = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

Comment: Seems UDID code is not working now. Can you please confirm? I tried on Xcode 8.2.1 with iOS 10.2 device.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.2+ proper way to get UUID:

```
if let UUID = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor {
  print("UUID: \(UUID.UUIDString)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting **UUID** in **Swift 3.0**:

```
let UUIDValue = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```