# Save a text file on iOS Directories from app

Tags: ios, ios7, uniqueidentifier

I am developing a program where I need to store a unique **device_id** since I cant get a unique identifier (like **MAC Address**) for every device, because it is deprecated by **Apple**.

What I want to do is, store a file in a specific directory of iOS where even the user deletes my iOS app this file wont be deleted. I am saying this because I used `NSUserDefaults` but the data stored from it get deleted if the user deletes its application.

*P.S Or if there is an alternative way to identify every device with its unique_id, suggestions are welcomed!*

Comment: It's against the terms of your developer contract to uniquely identify a device in any way other than using the vendorIdentifier for the device, especially without user consent.

Comment: Yes I have seen the documentation, but vendorforIdentifier returns the same value every time, and this is not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use KeyChain to save info that should not be deleted together with app.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html

UPDATE

This SO thread could be useful for you [Saving/Reading to/from KeyChain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535639/how-to-use-keychain-for-saving-password-like-generickeychain-sample-code)

Comment: are you sure keychain data isn't deleted if you delete the app?

Comment: KeyChain does not delete data because I have seen an example, but what I want to know is: If I save a value with a specific key in Keychain, accessing this value from other user for this key does return the same result?

Comment: @jcesar The keychain *may* be purged if the device has no other apps installed with the same keychain group! but in practice it's never been. Now with iCloud Keychain, I doubt it ever will.

Comment: @jcesar yes, I am sure. Common problem it is  "How to delete data from keychain" not how to save it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747404/delete-keychain-items-when-an-app-is-uninstalled

Comment: On MacOS every user account has its own keychain. Do we already have multiple user accounts for iOS7?

Comment: Avt that was simply a wonderfull answer! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to store a unique device_id since I cant get a unique
>   identifier

It is not 100% correct. You can use

```
[ UIDevice currentDevice ].identifierForVendor
```

From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) :

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the
>   same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned
>   for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for
>   apps on different devices regardless of vendor.
>
> Normally, the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store.
>   I the app was not installed from the app store (such as enterprise
>   apps and apps still in development), then a vendor identifier is
>   calculated based on the app’s bundle ID. The bundle ID is assumed to
>   be in reverse-DNS format.
>
> On iOS 6, the first two components of the bundle ID are used to
>   generate the vendor ID. if the bundle ID only has a single component,
>   then the entire bundle ID is used. On IOS 7, all components of the
>   bundle except for the last component are used to generate the vendor
>   ID. If the bundle ID only has a single component, then the entire
>   bundle ID is used.

Comment: I dont need to use the same id for every device. I want to identify device and for every device gets its unique id, but this is not allowed by apple, thats why I am asking about saving data without beeing deleted when the app gets uninstalled.

Comment: "A different value is returned ... and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor." For different devices it is different!

Comment: Refer to the first paragraph and you will understand what I am saying. The same device it refers to iPhone 4, 4s, 5, 5s. That means Ill have only 4 unique id. This was the problem that made me start looking for another way to identify a specific device like MAC Address does.

Comment: I do not think "devices" - is a model here. I think "devices" means particular instance.

Comment: Maybe, I don't know exactly but the idea is that I have tried it on my app and this was a major bug, because it generated the same values in 3 iPhone 5.

Comment: Thank you for information. I am using it in my current project. May be I need to check does it work as I expect or not.