# How to store data in Keychain?

Tags: ios, keychain

I want to know how to store data or like username/password in `keychain` ?
Is it good to store data in `NSUserdefault` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Never** store username/password in `NSUSerDefaults` because it is not secure. The data in `NSUSerDefaults` is stored in plain text in a .plist file and can be viewed with no jailbreak required using tools like iExplorer.

Here's how to save and read from Keychain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11541791/1738639