# AppsFlyer: Is there way to find if user reinstalls the app

Tags: appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I am trying to find if the users current app install if the first or if its a reinstall. Is there any way to determine this using iOS SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `getAppsFlyerUID` API and compare the ID's you are getting.

Swift:

```
let appsflyerId = AppsFlyerTracker.shared().getAppsFlyerUID()
```

Objective-C:

```
NSString *appsflyerId = [AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker].getAppsFlyerUID;
```

For every new install, you should see a new AppsFlyer ID.

For this to work in between app reinstalls, you'll have to keep the "old" AppsFlyer ID in a persistent data storage like [KeyChain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535639/how-to-use-keychain-for-saving-password-like-generickeychain-sample-code/11541791#11541791) or an internal BI system - so you can compare (or check if a previous ID exists).